# Pinning the accepted answer to top of list, or not

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see there's a plan for SE to change the way the accepted answer is displayed.

At the moment, the AA is the first answer you see in the list, unless you've gone and changed the sort order which 99% of readers don't do.

The planned alternative is to display all answers sorted specifically on vote score.

Further information: [Unpinning the accepted answer from the top of the list of answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369568/unpinning-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list-of-answers)

Most questions won't noticeably change, but an example post where this matters: [Is it safe to cut off from the inside of my helmet?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/is-it-safe-to-cut-off-from-the-inside-of-my-helmet)

The accepted answer has a score of -2 and the best answer has +10.

What do you prefer, and why?  We have the option to express an preference.

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19728/should-we-unpin-the-accepted-answer-from-the-top-of-the-list

Answer (score 2):

My vote is yes [or is it a no? :-)] - unpin the accepted answer. Even if just for the sake of the example you brought up, because of the dangerous advice in the AA.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a few posts where the accepted answer is the "wrong" answer. I suppose if there were a way to detect controversial best answers (where the highest-rated answer scores much higher than the accepted answer), a caution box could be slapped on the best answer. No idea if that's technically possible in SE.